# Multi Formula for Excel to IF Equals copy from another cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been trying multiple formula to get results for Column D as shown below...(column `d` is normally empty. I tried matching, if, and lookup formulas and have yet been able to successfully complete the task). Column `A` contains random ID numbers. Column `B` contains the "parent id numbers. I need a formula for IF column `B` is greater than zero look in column A for that number... THEN copy from column c that cell value. I have used this but wont copy `c` value when going down the list `=IF(C3>0,LOOKUP(C3,A2:A20001,D2))`

```
+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| Column A | Column B | Column C  | Column D |
+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
|      279 |        0 | P12345    |          |
|      281 |      279 | 69856     | P12345   |
|      282 |      279 | 656898    | P12345   |
|      283 |        0 | 6464845   |          |
|      301 |      285 | 12156498  |          |
|      322 |      279 | 6588446   | P12345   |
+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: thanks for the edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **D1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(IF(B1>0,VLOOKUP(B1,$A$1:$C$6,3,FALSE),""),"")
```

and copy down.

[image]

Comment: If it's safe to assume that `0` is not a valid parent ID (will not be present in column A), then you can simplify: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,$A$1:$C$6,3,FALSE),"")`